# swprintf() with narrow strings

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

The following line of code gives garbage with Visual Studio 2010:

```
swprintf(buf, L"Value is %s", "abcd");
```

However, the same code works fine on Linux.

By trial, I could make it work by using %S instead of %s under Visual Studio.

```
swprintf(buf, L"Value is %S", "abcd");
```

I am wondering if this is a bug in Visual Studio 2010 or am I missing something. Regards.

Comment: This is the rare case of a question which can and should legitimately tagged both C++ and C.

Comment: @Deduplicator Some library functions seemingly common to both C and C++ do actually have some differences between them. Unless the OP is absolutely certain that the answer is the same for both languages, and there's a concrete reason why a single language tag is insufficient, I think the OP was right to only tag it as C++.

Comment: @hvd: I was not implying that the OP was imprudent or did mistag, just that in this case C applies as well and equally well. Thus, I suggested adding C. I'm sorry if I gave you a different impression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "bug," though the behavior is by design.  The initial Visual C++ implementation of the wide string printf and scanf functions predated their standardization in C, and in some cases the behavior deviates from what is required by the C Standard Library specification.

In the C Standard Library specification, a `%s` or `%c` format specifier must always be paired with a `char` array or element, and the `l` length modifier must be used when a `wchar_t` array or element is provided.

In the Visual C++ implementation of these functions ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx)), the `%s` and `%c` format specifiers expect a corresponding argument of the "natural" width.  For the narrow string printf and scanf functions, a `char` pointer or element is required and for the wide string functions a `wchar_t` pointer or element is required.  To pass a string of the "other" width, the `%S` and `%C` format specifiers may be used.  Alternatively, the `h` and `l` length modifiers may be used to explicitly specify that the string argument is a narrow or wide string.

Among other advantages, the Visual C++ implementation of these functions made it possible to easily migrate old code to use Unicode strings via [the `_TCHAR` mappings in `<tchar.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx).  It is unfortunate that what was standardized was different from what had already been implemented in the Visual C++ implementation (I am not familiar with the history here; it may be that what was standardized matched another implementation.).

Comment: UCS-2 before they moved to UTF-16; UTF-8 is Unicode too. It is at least equally unfortunate that they moved to UCS-2 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: It was invented around that time though, and that does not change the fact that it is unfortunate imho. Also, it does not change the fact that pretending only UTF-16 is unicode is at least misleading.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft implementation of wide `printf` and `scanf` functions is not standard conforming, thus you get different results on Linux (standard-conforming) and Windows (broken).

[The link Matt posted in his answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) points to a MSDN page hinting at that misbehavior:

> The C, S, and Z type characters, and **the behavior of the c and s type characters** when they are used with the printf and wprintf functions, are Microsoft extensions and are **not ANSI compatible**. Visual C++ does not support the F type character.

Emphasis mine. BTW: Here ANSI means all C standards, and by extension the C++ standards.

The specific issue is that MS redefined those conversion specifiers (`c` `s`) to expect UTF-16 when used with wide functions.

Answer (score 0):

%s and %S have different meanings:

s: When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a wide-character string. Characters are displayed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.

S: When used with printf functions, specifies a wide-character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte character string. Characters are displayed up to the first null character or until the precision value is reached.

This is why

```
swprintf(buf, L"Value is %S", "abcd");
```

shows the correct value.

The MSDN link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx).

Comment: That does not explain the OPs observations, though you got at least half the explanation.

Comment: This answer should point out that this interpretation of `%s` does not correspond to the C99 standard.

Answer (score 0):

"abcd" is a narrow string since you ommitted the 'L'. swprintf() expects all of its %s string inputs to be wide.