# How to copy/convert a char string to a wchar_t string in C?

Tags: c, string, char, wchar-t

I looked around, and found a program where `swprintf` is used from the `<wchar.h>` library. However i tried that method, and it didn't work. It just says program.exe has stopped working when i run the program. I copied the sample program i found, into my own compiler-- which didn't work either. I'll copy the program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{

 wchar_t NameBuffer[100];
 char *str1 ="c:\\Program Files\\test.txt";

   swprintf(NameBuffer,100,L"%s",str1);
   printf("%s\n",NameBuffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code or is it my compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting with mbstowcs():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

 wchar_t NameBuffer[100];
 char *str1 ="c:\\Program Files\\test.txt";

   mbstowcs(NameBuffer, str1, 100);
   wprintf(L"%ls\n",NameBuffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, in the printf line

```
printf("%s\n",NameBuffer);
```

`NameBuffer` is not a (converted) value of type `char *` and therefore you invoke Undefined Behaviour by not matching the `%s` and its corresponding argument.

Try

```
wprintf(L"%ls\n", NameBuffer);
```

or

```
printf("%ls\n", NameBuffer);
```

---

You may also want to define `str1` as pointer to const

```
const char *str1 = "c:\\Program Files\\test.txt";
```

Comment: Still no good. Is it working for you? Can you run it and check please?

Comment: http://ideone.com/DFmuu3 (with `wprintf()`) and http://ideone.com/DgzU2V (with `printf()`). Cannot mix the two because the first one called sets `stdout` to a mode that makes it incompatible with the other.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine I can test on. I heard that support for C99 in Windows library is missing for some things; don't know for sure what is missing.

Comment: @pmg: [Microsoft's C94 implementation is non-conforming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23572438/4231385). @RizvanFerdous has to write `swprintf(NameBuffer,100,L"%hs",str1);` (or sth. similar), since `%s` expects `wchar_t`, because `swprintf()` is a wide character function. Take a look at [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx).

Comment: Okay none of these are working for me. The reason i wanted to do this is because i wanted to **replace** any **blank space** in a string with a **+**, and use the new string to open a URL using `system (start www.example.com`

For example, the 
_User name:_ Rashed Ferdous _would 
convert from_ **Rashed Ferdous** _to_ **Rashed+Ferdous** 
_and then be used in a URL like this:_ www.example.com/Rashed+Ferdous _so the code would look like:_ 
`system (start  www.example.com/Rashed+Ferdous);` 

Is there a way i can do it without converting the `wchar_t` string?

Comment: hmmm ... `system()` uses `char *`. Why do you need to introduce `wchar_t *` into the equation?

Comment: To replace spaces in `name` with plus signs: `char *cur = name; for (; *cur; cur++) if (*cur == ' ') *cur = '+';` (should also work with `wchar_t` provided you use `L'+'`)

Comment: What you mentioned works for `char*`, but not for `wchar_t*` (including `L'+'` ). If `system()` works with `char*`, can you please include an example of the syntax below? Because i tried with `char*`, and couldn't make it work, which is why i used `wchar_t`.

Comment: I'll try Monday (if I remember) at work, with a Windows machine. But try specifying `https` (or `http`) in your start: `system("start https://www.example.com/Rashed+Ferdous")`

Comment: It worked! `system()` works with `char*`. I was just using wrong syntax. Thanks!